Replace elements while traversing DOM tree using html5ever
backgrounds
I need to find and replace some tags in html fragments, for example, replace
<div class="not-replaced">
    <i18n>Hello World</i18n>
</div>

with
<div class="not-replaced">
    <span class="i18n" data-location="/index.html:$/i18n">Hello World</span>
</div>

what I have done so far
I am trying to achieve this through html5ever and markup5ever_rcdom, I think I need a recursive function to traverse the node tree, but I am not able to come up with a valid one, the signature of the function to create new element is RcDom::create_element(&mut self), so my recursive function needs two arguments:

dom: &mut RcDom or mut dom: RcDom to create new element with
node: Rc<Node> to traverse

It is difficult because I can not pass arguments like self.traverse(&mut dom, dom.document).
The only valid signature I could find out so far is fn traverse(&self, dom: &RcDom, node: &Rc<Node>), but it is useless as dom is not mutable, I can not invoke create_element on it.
This is the piece of codes I have right now:
  fn expand_macro(&mut self) {
    let mut html = File::open("index.html").unwrap();
    let mut dom = html5ever::parse_fragment(
      RcDom::default(),
      html5ever::ParseOpts::default(),
      QualName::new(None, ns!(html), local_name!("div")),
      vec![],
    )
    .from_utf8()
    .read_from(&mut html)
    .unwrap();

    self.traverse(&mut dom, dom.document);
  }

  fn traverse(&mut self, dom: &mut RcDom, node: Rc<Node>) {
  }

what I need
how to rewrite the codes, so I can have access to a &mut RcDom together with a Rc<Node> to traverse.
or some other suggestions to accomplish the same goal as I described in backgrounds.
Thanks, any help is appreciated!

This can be regarded as a "modify-when-iterating" problem, my solution is:

collect all elements which need to be processed in first iteration,
then apply these changes in second iteration

the code snip looks like this:
pub struct HtmlMacro {
  pub location: String,
  pub parent_node: Rc<Node>,
  pub index: usize,
  pub text: String,
}

fn expand_macro_html(source: String, source_path: &Path) -> String {
  // parse dom
  let mut dom = html5ever::parse_fragment(/* options */)
                  .from_utf8()
                  .one(source.as_bytes());

  // the first iteration only needs a readonly reference to dom
  // collect_html_macros(dom: &RcDom, file_path: &Path) -> Vec<HtmlMacro>
  let macros = collect_html_macros(&dom, source_path);

  // the second iteration has a mutable reference to dom
  // expand macros
  for m in macros {
    let mut children = m.parent_node.children.borrow_mut();
    let expanded_macro = dom.create_element(/* new element */);
    children[m.index] = expanded_macro;
  }

  // serialize
  // return serialized document
}

